# How is it called when we explicitly quantify a letter or digit instead of spelling it out multiple times?

Tags: language, reading, linguistics, behavior, language-processing

When we need to repeat a letter or digit several times (for example when spelling out a number or an acronym) it is easier to explicitly quantify it instead of spelling it out repeatedly: for example we will spell *I-triple-E* instead of *I-E-E-E*, or *triple-five* instead of *five-five-five* (in French: SSII spelled as *deux-es-deux-i* instead of *es-es-i-i*), we will write W3 instead of WWW, etc. My intuition tells me that when we repeat the same letter/digit multiple times the listener will need to count them, and may get confused, while if we warn him/her that there will be a repetition and give the final count of items, he/she avoids counting operation and therefore also the risk of miscounting.

My question is: how is this operation called, and do you know if anyone has studied it (in a psychological or cognitive frame)?

Comment: First time I heard such was the TV program [That Was the Week That Was,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Was_the_Week_That_Was) or "TW3". My idea is that it is just easier to say (say "WWW" ten times) and avoids repetition which is boring.

Comment: Interesting example, since formally it should rather be (TW)3. My question is whether this has been studied from a psycho-cognitive point of view.